# Multiplayer movement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

this is my client: http://pastebin.com/C9PHzTQg
this is my server: http://pastebin.com/j2dfL84d

Now is "multiplayer" rect's, but how to do movement?

I am send to 'b' - "UP", "LEFT", "RIGHT", "DOWN" and how to handle ant move player?

Sorry for my bad english language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to learn prototypical inheritance! As it is, each `Player` will have it's own copy of the `draw` method, so put `draw` on `Player.prototype` instead:

```
var Player = function(context, x, y) {
    this.context = context;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Player.prototype = {
    draw: function() {
        this.context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 16, 16);
    }
};
```

Then, I suggest you add a `move` method to `Player`:

```
Player.prototype = {
    draw: function() {
        this.context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 16, 16);
    },

    move: function(direction) {
        // direction is "UP", "DOWN", "LEFT" or "RIGHT"
        switch(direction) {
            case "UP":
                this.y += 16;
                break;
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Then, in your message handler, you just have to:

```
socket.on('b', function(data) {
    players[data.player].move(data.direction);
    draw();
});
```

In the server, you would `emit('b', { player: playerId, direction: "UP" }`, for example.

**Update:** Instead of `draw` inside `socket.on('b', ...` above, you could have something like:

```
setInterval(draw, 100);
```

To redraw every 100 ms. It depends on the type of game, I guess.

Comment: Linus G Thiel, thanks for fantastic code snippets! I am think this is very good idea and must work, but...
my redraw code is in draw(), but don't move, don't redraw player in new positions. :-(. In server-side i write - "socket.emit('b', {
   player: myNumber,
   direction: 'UP'
    });" and Very thanks for code snippets! ;-)

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you definitely want to call draw as well after receiving a `'b'`. Also, `Player` should probably have a reference to `context` instead of a global variable -- updated above.

Comment: Thanks for help, thanks for answers, but for my don't work.
I added to client: http://pastebin.com/SSFhEkw5 and server-side: http://pastebin.com/7fEYBGGy  
In my brain - must work, but don't work. Sorry I new in this. :-)
And thanks, thanks!

Comment: Why did you move `socket.on('b', ...)` into `draw`? That seems... Weird.

Comment: Ups, I done: http://pastebin.com/sWxZneTZ
First player - players[1] can move, but other client don't see where this move and if other client connected position get 0-0.
Hm, I don't have more ideas :-(
Thanks.